# How to deep compare/match objects in an array, based on an array of strings property in each object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

The array with objects:

```
var myArr = [ { user: 'jane', properties: ['prop1', 'prop2'] }
              { user: 'bob', properties: ['prop1', 'prop4'] }
              { user: 'dave', properties: ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'] }
              { user: 'tim', properties: ['prop4', 'prop2', 'prop3'] } 
];
```

Is there a way in pure javascript or perhaps using lodash to obtain the users that have at least one property in common? The output should indicate which user matches with which user, without duplicates.

I've tried a number of things, but unfortunately was not able to get the desired output.

Comment: can you give a sample output? would it be an array or an object?

Comment: @Jayce444 Any output is good enough, as long as the output shows which users match with which users (matching pairs). The precise structure does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution below uses a `Set` to determine whether matching properties exist, combined with a `reduce()` operation to output matching user pairs:

```js
const array = [{ user: 'jane', properties: ['prop1', 'prop2'] },
  { user: 'bob', properties: ['prop1', 'prop4'] },
  { user: 'dave', properties: ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'] },
  { user: 'tim', properties: ['prop4', 'prop2', 'prop3'] }];
  
const result = array.reduce((acc, val1, i, arr) => [
  ...acc,
  ...arr.slice(i + 1).filter(val2 => {
    const properties = [...val1.properties, ...val2.properties];
    return new Set(properties).size < properties.length;
  }).map(val2 => [val1.user, val2.user])
], []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. I hadn't considered this approach. Thank you @Robby Cornelissen

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map and Object, count the user occurrence for each properties, if it is same as length of array then there is atleast one property which occurs in all the users

```js
let matcher = (arr) => {
  let mapper = {}
  arr.forEach(v => {
  let { user, properties } = v
    properties.forEach(v => {
      if (mapper[v]) {
        mapper[v].set(user, (mapper[v].get(user) || 0) + 1)
      } else {
        mapper[v] = new Map()
        mapper[v].set(user, 1)
      }
    })
  })
  return Object.entries(mapper).some(([_, v]) => {
    let total = [...v].reduce((a, [_, b]) => a + b, 0)
    return total === arr.length
  })
}

let arr = [{user: 'jane',properties: ['prop1', 'prop2']}, {user: 'bob',properties: ['prop1', 'prop4']}, {user: 'dave',properties: ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']}, {user: 'tim',properties: ['prop4', 'prop2', 'prop3']}];

console.log(matcher(arr))

let arr2 = [{user: 'jane',properties: ['prop1', 'prop2']},{user: 'bob',properties: ['prop1', 'prop4']}]

console.log(matcher(arr2))
```

Comment: This does not answer this question, as it is of particular importance to know which users match with which users.

Comment: Some can be replaced with filter and you will get the prop which is common along all the users